# Memcached installation on Linux server

Tags: linux, memcached

I tried to install memcached on linux server. After successful completion of all installation steps(configure, make and make install), when I try to start memcached services, nothing happens. What could be the problem? Also I don find any conf file generated.

I used this to start memcached

```
memcached -m 2048 -d -l 172.17.111.111 11211 -u appadmin
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your expectations are but the command you provide will run memcached, which will start silently. You can check that memcached is running by using ps

```
ps -ef | grep memcached | grep -v grep
496   25480   1  0 07:20 ?    00:00:00 memcached -d -p 11211 -u memcached -l 192.168.254.188
```

or you can use netstat to see if it's listening

```
netstat -tnlp | grep 11211
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:11211         0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN  25791/memcached
tcp    0    0 :::11211              :::*                 LISTEN  25791/memcached
```

I've only ever installed memcached using my Linux distros package manager and in doing so get access to the distro's service control e.g.

```
service memcached start
Starting memcached:                                        [  OK  ]
service memcached status
memcached (pid  26330) is running...
service memcached stop
Stopping memcached:                                        [  OK  ]
```

or their /etc/init.d/memcached equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that memcached is running in your Server .
ie

```
ps -ef | grep memcached
```

This should show the running memcached process .
Else start the memcached from `/etc/init.d`

Normally memcached has conf file located in

```
/etc/sysconfig/memcached
```

From my memcached file

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/memcached

    PORT="11211"
    USER="memcached"
    MAXCONN="1024"
    CACHESIZE="64"
    OPTIONS=""
```